# Difference between single and double pointers appending

Tags: c, linked-list

This may be a stupid question but I really want to know why this happens. When trying to create an append function for linked lists why this single pointer solution do not work but when a double pointer is used it works?

**Single pointer:**

```
void append(node *head, int value){
node *current = head;
node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (new == NULL){
    printf("couldn't allocate memory");
    return;
}
new->value = value;
new->next = NULL;
if (head == NULL){
    head = new;
    return;
}
while (current->next != NULL)
    current = current->next;
current->next = new;
return;}
```

**Double pointer:**

```
void append(node **head, int value){
node *current = *head;
node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (new == NULL){
    printf("couldn't allocate memory");
    return;}
new->value = value;
new->next = NULL;
if (*head == NULL){
    *head = new;
    return;
}
while (current->next != NULL)
    current = current->next;
current->next = new;
return;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have your head in memory

 `-------------     ------------
 | head 0x10 |  -> |  0x20    |
 -------------     ------------`

0x10 is the address of head, not the address it's pointing to, the address it's pointing to is 0x20.

If you call `append` with just a single pointer, it'll make a copy of the head value to a local address of the function `append`
In that way, for `append` head could be:

 `-------------     ------------
 | head 0x25 |  -> |  0x20    |
 -------------     ------------`

So, the new address of head is **0x25**, pointing to **0x20**

If you make `head` inside the function to point to another address, e.g:

 `-------------     ------------
 | head 0x25 |  -> |  0x30    |
 -------------     ------------`

It'll be only the `head` inside the function that will point to a different address, in the caller function it will still be:

 `-------------     ------------
 | head 0x10 |  -> |  0x20    |
 -------------     ------------`

Because you are passing the pointer by value, so the function is making a copy of the pointer.
To address that you need to pass a pointer to a pointer, so your variable will be:

`local

-------------    -------------     ------------
| head 0x25 | -> | head 0x10 |  -> |  0x20    |
-------------    -------------     ------------`

Now you have a pointer to the caller pointer, so you can make changes to where it's pointing to and it will reflect on the caller head.

e.g

`local

-------------    -------------     ------------
| head 0x25 | -> | head 0x10 |  -> |  0x30    |
-------------    -------------     ------------`

Answer (score 2):

When a function is called with an argument a copy of that argument is created on the stack. So in a way, they are very similar to local variables.

In single pointer case the statement `head = new;` in effect just causes the change to argument `head`, and this change is not propagated back to the actual head passed.

In double pointer case you get the address of `head` which you are able to alter by doing `*head = new;`.